# Differential equations, follows that $k_0 \le -\alpha/p(0)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that $p \in C^1([0, 1])$ with $p(x) \ge \alpha > 0$ for all $x\in [0, 1]$ and $q \in C([0, 1])$ with $q(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$. Let $v_0 \in C^2([0, 1])$ be the unique solution of$$\begin{cases} -(pv_0')' + qv_0 = 0 & \text{on }[0, 1], \\ v_0(0) = 1,\,v_0(1) = 0.\end{cases}$$Set $k_0 = v_0'(0)$.

Does it necessarily follow that $k_0 \le -\alpha/p(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the writing I will use $v$ instead of $v_0$. Multiplying the equation by $v$ and integrating by parts we get
$$
p(0)\,v(0)+\int_0^1p\,|v'|^2+\int_0^1q\,|v|^2=0.
$$
This shows that $v'(0)\le0$. Since $q\ge0$ and $p\ge\alpha>0$ we have
$$
p(0)\,|v(0)|\ge\int_0^1p\,|v'|^2\ge\alpha\int_0^1|v'|^2.
$$
It is enough to prove that $\int_0^1|v'|^2\ge1$. Using that $v(0)=1$, $v(1)=0$ and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get
$$
1=\Bigl|\int_0^1v'\Bigr|\le\Bigl(\int_0^1|v'|^2\Bigr)^{1/2}\Bigl(\int_0^11\Bigr)^{1/2}.
$$